# Insert All causes unique constraint of primary key violated

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I am trying to use INSERT ALL to insert rows in my table.

```
INSERT ALL
INTO TABLE(C2, C3) VALUES ("Hello","World")
...
...
SELECT 1 from DUAL;
```

Column C1 of the table has constraint of primary key and its value is set as default next value of a sequence I created (this was done while table creation),

```
C1 NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT SEQUENCE1.NEXTVAL NOT NULL,
.
.
CONSTRAINT Constraint1 PRIMARY KEY (C1)
```

While running the insert all statemnt I get the error

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (databaseName.Constraint1 ) violated

Does it happen because insert all does some synced up insertion and the sequence is not increasing?
I am trying to use Insert ALL only for fresh insertion (not copying from source to destination table)
I do not want to use Insert query for each row.
This is some research kind of thing I am trying.

Comment: Which DBMS (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle…) are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle DB

Comment: No, it is not happening because of an issue of the sequence.  It is happening because some other column has a unique constraint that you are violating.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `INSERT ALL` only generates one sequence value for all the rows inserted, causing the constraint violation.  Replace the `INSERT ALL` with multiple `SELECT ... FROM DUAL UNION ALL` subqueries and the sequences will work as expected.

This code will call the `NEXTVAL` for each row:

```
insert into table1(c2, c3)
select 'Hello', 'World' from dual union all
select 'Hello', 'World' from dual;
```

As a bonus, the `UNION ALL` trick tends to run faster than `INSERT ALL`.